# Difference in application between Standard Type Bulb Pipette Filler and Universal Type?

Tags: equipment

I want to ask what is the difference in terms of application between the HHH (Heinz Herenz Hamburg) Bulb Pipette Filler Standard Type (1081801) and the HHH Bulb Pipette Filler Universal Type (1081802)?

Answer (score 2):

They both basically have same functions with same operations. However, universal type is longer than standard type with an adapter for pipette head (see the picture below: standard type is to your left).

[image: D&N Bulbs]

Note: The bulbs shown are Deutsch-Neumann, but they are similar to HHH.

Comment: What's the advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Are they used for the same  pipette with the same measurement capacity or they provide different capacity of suction? Example : one is for pipette of X ml and the other can be used for pipette with higher ">X" ml.